# Custom URI from iframe in IE opens only about:blank

Tags: html, internet-explorer, iframe

I have a page which contains some 'custom://uri' links. When this page is opened manually, it is working correctly. When this page is opened from `<a target='_blank'>` in iframe, tab behaves differently: all custom URI links are broken and lead to about:blank.

Same happens when I include custom URI links into the iframe directly. Here's the code:

```
<a target ='_blank' href='custom://hi/'>Test</a>
```

Here's [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/farb987s/1/).
If I'd enter the 'custom://hi/' into address bar directly, I'll see the custom URI handler error page (expected because there's no such URI handler).
Same with `<a>` with custom URI somewhere in the top page.
Hovewer if I'd press Test from inside jsfiddle iframe (or any other iframe), I'll see about:blank.

Why is this happening and how to avoid that?

Comment: I don't understand. Do you have a custom URI handler installed? What does it do (what does "it works correctly" mean exactly?) What sense does having `target=_blank` make in this context in the first place?

Comment: Yes, I do have custom URI handler installed. I used `custom://` stub to demonstrate that issue doesn't depend on my handler. You can use `skype://` if you want.
`target = _blank` is required by design. I need to show the page in a new tab/window.

Comment: But I thought custom URI handlers can only call an executable, not display content in a browser window?

Comment: That's right, I'd like them to call an executable.
I need to open page which will contain custom URIs from an iframe. The fact that I try to call them directly in jsfiddle is just for easier demonstration of the issue.

Comment: But why do you need `target=_blank` in the first place, when the URI handler won't actually open a window? Is it because if the URI handler is *not* installed, the browser's error page will show up? Does calling the custom URI from the frame work if you don't use `target=_blank`?

Comment: Ok, I'll try to explain differently. In the app it's `iframe with <a target=_blank> ---> page in a new tab with <a href='custom://'>` It doesn't work. I've shortened it to `iframe with <a target=_blank href='custom'>` because it's simpler and still reproduces. Notice that `top with <a target=_blank href='custom'>` works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110264/discussion-between-anatoly-sazanov-and-pekka-).

Comment: OK, I understand a little bit better. Weird, not sure what needs to be done. What browsers have you reproduced this with? You tagged the question `internet-explorer`, have you tried with any others? (Can't chat right now, sorry)

Comment: Ok then. Other browsers work perfectly, but we need to support IE10/11 as well. It really looks like some IE-specific security feature, but I'm unable to find any related info.